# Get user's email from "assigned to" field at task workflow of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I need to get user's email from "assigned to" field at task workflow of sharepoint
For example when i send email, i use this code:

```
SPListItem wfItem = onWorkflowActivated1.WorkflowProperties.Item;
            SPFieldUser assignedTo = (SPFieldUser)wfItem.Fields["Assigned To"];

            SPFieldUserValue user = (SPFieldUserValue)assignedTo.GetFieldValue(wfItem["Assigned To"].ToString());
            string assigneeEmail = user.User.Email;

            sendEmailToAssignee.To = assigneeEmail;
            sendEmailToAssignee.Subject = "New work order has been created.";
            sendEmailToAssignee.Body"Bla bla bla";
```

in "Assigned To" field ( i created) in LitsItem, i have value domain\my_account so I can get my email my_mail@example.com to variable assigneeEmail. Now I need it but in task. In "Assign To" field in task, how can we go it?

Comment: eee, What’s the problem? Task is SPListItem, you can use your code for task too, only you must get SPListItem instance of task, e.g. SPListItem task = taskList.GetItemById(taskId), where taskList – your tasks list and taskId – your task id

Comment: I have a domain account. In domain account in Email field i have an email. If we want to send an email, we need value "my_mail@example.com" set to variable assigneeEmail. But in field Assigned To (I created),there will be domain account for example his_company\his_account.So if that domain account is set to assigneeEmail,the email could not be sent.We need email address. This code do the job-get email field from account domain. But this code is for a field in ListItem.how do i do the same with task (get email address form Assigned To field in task form edit.I new, can you give me sample code?

Comment: Do you want get value from AD field by user account name? For this you could use DirectoryEntry (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) and DirectorySearcher (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) class, e.g. Filter for DirectorySearcher  “(SAMAccountName=accountnamewithoutdomainname)”

Comment: I think this code will work for me.   SPFieldUser assignedTo = (SPFieldUser)task.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo];
SPFieldUserValue user = (SPFieldUserValue) assignedTo.GetFieldValue(task[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo].ToString());
SPUser userObject = user.User; but i dont know what task is. task is a name of what?

Comment: task is a instance of SPListItem. In my first comment i wrote about it

Comment: Can you write full demo (i think it's just several code lines) to get email from Assigned To field of instance of task listitem. I'm new and now I have to learn as much as possible at same time. I don't really have good basic knowledge about it. Now i'm learning.

Comment: e.g. http://pastebin.com/N62vry8r

Answer (score 1):

If there a field called "Assign To" any where in sharepoint (list of any type), you can use the same code, provided "Assign To" is of Type "People/Group"

```
SPFieldUserValue myUser = new SPFieldUserValue(SPWeb Object, taskItem["<<AssignTo_INTERNAL_NAME>>"]);
string emailAddress = myUser.User.Email;
```